# how to get max using template metaprograming using variadic template class

Tags: c++

Below I am trying to get a simple max value from a list of traits containing SOME_VAL at compile time:

```
struct A_Traits { enum { SOME_VAL=5 }; };
struct B_Traits { enum { SOME_VAL=6 }; };
struct C_Traits { enum { SOME_VAL=4 }; };

template<typename T>
T MAX(T t1, T t2)
{
    return t1>t2?t1:t2;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct max_calculator
{
    enum { MAX_VAL = MAX(max_calculator<typename T::SOME_VAL>::MAX_VAL, // line 65
                         max_calculator<Args...>::MAX_VAL) };
};
template<typename T>
struct max_calculator<T>
{
    enum { MAX_VAL = T::SOME_VAL };
};

int main()
{
    cout << max_calculator<A_Traits>::MAX_VAL << endl;
    cout << max_calculator<A_Traits, B_Traits>::MAX_VAL << endl;  // line 79
}
```

However I get a compile error of:

```
variadic.cpp: In instantiation of 'struct max_calculator<A_Traits, B_Traits>':
variadic.cpp:79:47:   required from here
variadic.cpp:65:10: error: no type named 'SOME_VAL' in 'struct A_Traits'
```

Any idea whats wrong or better ideas to do the same at compile time?

Comment: `typename T::SOME_VAL` should be just `T`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Thanks, I look so dumb now! :) Please put it as an answer for me to accept. However, I had to cast the outputs of max_calculator to int for MAX template function to work otherwise, it sees them as different enums from different classes. Any way to get around that?

Comment: @Blinu `MAX<int>(a, b)` is shorter

Comment: You can close this question as a typo.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Does that actually fix it? Doesn't [appear](https://godbolt.org/z/FAQj8Z) to.

Comment: @cigien As I said `T`, not `T::SOME_VAL`, as you put. And make the function `constexpr`

Comment: Thanks you @PiotrSkotnicki. cigien - yes it does, but you have to make MAX constexpr as Piotr mentioned.

Comment: Ok, I tried that, but I still can't get it to [work](https://godbolt.org/z/RL_dsj). that's not your problem, so you can close the question, of course :)

Comment: @cigien max_calculator<T>::MAX_VAL not max_calculator<T::SOME_VAL>::MAX_VAL

Comment: Yes, that's what I have on line 65 in the link in the last comment. Am I missing something else? Don't worry about having to explain anything to me though, you're the asker. Just making sure this solves your problem.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I do not see a way to close this. Possible for you to close or perhaps if its alright for you to post as answer.

Comment: @cigien Ok! All good with me - it works like a charm, was a dumb mistake :-) Anyway for your issue make it MAX<int>(....

Comment: Ok, that works, thanks :) I'd say the error was more than a typo, since 3 different things have to be changed. You should be able to close the question yourself, or you could post an answer with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

`std::max` has a constexpr overload for `std::initialiser_list<T>`, you can expand your pack in one place

```
template<typename... Args>
struct max_calculator
{
    enum { MAX_VAL = std::max({ Args::SOME_VAL... }) };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For the benefit of everyone visting this later - the fixed program based on Piotr's answers in the comments section is:

```
struct A_Traits { enum { SOME_VAL=5 }; };
struct B_Traits { enum { SOME_VAL=6 }; };
struct C_Traits { enum { SOME_VAL=4 }; };

template<typename T>
constexpr T MAX(T t1, T t2)
{
    return t1>t2?t1:t2;
}

template<typename T, typename... Args>
struct max_calculator
{
    enum { MAX_VAL =MAX<uint8_t>(max_calculator<T>::MAX_VAL,
                                 max_calculator<Args...>::MAX_VAL) };
};
template<typename T>
struct max_calculator<T>
{
    enum { MAX_VAL = T::SOME_VAL };
};

int main()
{
    cout << max_calculator<A_Traits>::MAX_VAL << endl;
    cout << max_calculator<A_Traits, B_Traits>::MAX_VAL << endl;
    cout << max_calculator<A_Traits, B_Traits, C_Traits>::MAX_VAL << endl;
}
```